# Two motors to drive multiple shafts

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have multiple shafts I’d like to rotate independently and sequentially.
I’m looking for a two motor solution - like a mechanical multiplexer - so one motor chooses the shaft and the second motor engages to actuate it.

Any references / videos / better ideas are welcome.

Comment: What have you found so far so we don't waste our effort duplicating or suggesting things you have refused already.

Comment: Nothing useful so far 

Comment: Use one motor to move the other  along a slide across the back of the shafts. Have a spur gear engage as they pass. You may get a little rotation on each shaft as the drive unit passes by.

Comment: I would just split up the drive motor shaft with gears or belts to multiple electromagnetic clutches. It just complicates things using a *rotary* motor to for the clutch/selection when the rotary motion is unnecessary because now you need position control and lots of mechanics.

Comment: How many are the *multiple* shafts?